# How to get line breaks to translate to paragraphs?

Tags: tinymce, visual-editor

How can I get the line breaks that I make in the TinyMCE editor to translate into new lines in  the web page. Suddenly all posts when actually previewed on the theme are walls of text. In the final post's source code there are no surrounding <p> elements surrounding the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, line breaks in the TinyMCE editor *are* convered into `<p></p>` paragraphs. Either your theme or a plugin is disabling this functionality.

To figure out which, you need to:

1. Disable all plugins and see if this fixes the problem.

   - If it does, then re-enable your plugins one at a time to see which one is breaking the paragraph features.
2. Switch back to the default theme (either TwentyTen or TwentyEleven).

   - If this fixes the problem, then it's your *theme* that is causing the issue.  [Ask a new question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about fixing your theme and be sure to tell us what theme you're using.